# Propagation of uncertainties when the parameter being calculated is not normally distributed, and neither are its components

Tags: distributions, uncertainty, error-propagation

I have an equation (linked here for simplicity as i can't format https://i.stack.imgur.com/l9bZS.jpg)

The parameters Tc, T0, Zb and Z0 are fixed.

hr is normally distributed

K is normally distributed in log10 space (assumedly i replace this in the equation with $10^{Ki}$ to get it normally distributed)

H0 is normally distributed in log10 space (assumedly i replace this in the equation with $10^{Hi}$ to get it normally distributed)

If I use the uncertainty propagation equation i.e.

$s_q=\sqrt((\frac{dq}{dKi} \times std(Ki))^2+(\frac{dq}{dHi} \times std(Hi))^2+(\frac{dq}{dhr} \times std(hr))^2)$

I get a value out.. however q is not normally distributed, so what meaning does the value I get out have? Is there a valid way to use uncertainty propagation in this case?

Comment: What is the relationship between the graph in the image and the formula shown beneath it?

Comment: @whuber it is the distribution of q after monte carlo simulation with the distributions of the input variables